# To find given set is open, closed, bound, closure, interior

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Consider the set $S = \{x \in \mathbb R^2 :-1 < x_i \leq 1,\; i = 1,2\}$. Is $S$ open? Is it
closed? Is it bounded? Is it compact? Find the closure, interior, and boundary of S.

Aside from the definitions, kindly let me know how to approach/solve the problem given.

Comment: Maybe you could show your work and where you are getting stuck...

Comment: Open/closed: Can you find a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ from $S$ that converges to a point outside of $S$? Do _you_ think it is bounded? If so, by what?

Comment: Maybe try drawing a picture of the set. Use a dashed line to indicate $<$ borders, a solid line to indicate $\leq$ borders.

Answer (score 2):

I am adding the picture of $S$ here **just** to find out what the comments and Isaac's answer mean. I can't  upload it in a site as a link as Isaac suggested. 
[image]

Comment: I like pictures, for explanatory purposes...+1

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to get a good idea of what $S$ looks like. Draw $S$, using solid lines or dotted lines to indicate whether or not an element on the boundary is included in $S$ or not. It is a good idea for you to try and draw this yourself.

Once you have drawn the picture, ask yourself the following question: What are the "pictorial" meanings behind the abstract notions of "open", "closed", and "bounded"? What do you know about compact sets and how they related to these ideas? Similarly, what can you glean from the suggestive names "closure", "interior" and "boundary" when applied to this picture of $S$?

It would also help if you first tried answering this question when $S$ is defined in $\mathbb{R}^1$. What does it look like then?

Comment: I made a picture. Would you like me to add it to your answer? you can edit it next as it will be yours.

Comment: I actually think it would be better if the OP draws this set himself. Perhaps link to it as a comment?